# pandas dataframe.to_sql turn off automatic timezone offset

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Pandas DataFrame.to_sql automatically adds FixedOffsetTimezone to dataframe. My initial dataframe index doesnt have timezone:
[image]

However, when I try to save dataframe and retrieve values, returned index has timezone -4:

[image]

[image]

Does anyone know how to turn it off? Pandas documentation doesnt mention it [dataframe.to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)

```
ats.all.to_sql("ats_all", con, if_exists="replace")
```

where con=SQL Alchemy connection

Database=Postgres with pgAdmin 4

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution: the problem was indeed in the postgres settings. Database timezone was set to -4. Here's the sql to set timezone to 0

```
--check current timezone setting
SELECT current_setting('TIMEZONE');

--need to restart database for the change to kick in
ALTER DATABASE postgres SET timezone TO 'GMT';
```